# Jquery apply css not to second class

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I've got some element with variable hight (dep. on content)

say div.container

I want to make it collapsable with css animation.

So first get the initial hight:

```
var mnh = $('.container').outerHeight();
```

then I set the hight to css (to make css animation work)

```
$('.container').css('height' , mnh + 'px');
```

and the I set the element to collapsed state

```
$('.mobile-navigation').addClass('collapsed');
```

while i've got

```
.container.collapsed{
 height: 50px;
}
```

in my css

The I want to change state with

```
$('.my-control').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.container').toggleClass('collapsed');
})
```

but it does not work, because, as I understand, when I'm setting height to element via jquery, it sets the initial height to both collapsed and not, and overwrites the height:50px property in my css.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `.css` will set the styles as inline. So styles under classes cannot override it. The only option is to use `!important` in the class.

Comment: maybe $('.container').css('height' , null) in the click-event function

Comment: how could I forget to try !important. So dumb ) Thx )